# spring-boot & gae error : The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: spring-boot, google-app-engine

i used gcloud sample : https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/1e53a6265871fd5ed234e4a2f5bdd62e3ae9655a/flexible/java-11/springboot-helloworld/README.md

deployed successfully.
use appengine-generated addresses rather than custom domains.
accessing a browser returned error message

response

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <title>404 Page not found</title>
</head>

<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
    <h1>Error: Page not found</h1>
    <h2>The requested URL was not found on this server.</h2>
    <h2></h2>
</body>

</html>
```

i maked spring-boot project, but return message same too

This is app.yaml file i create:

```
runtime: java
env: flex
runtime_config:
  operating_system: ubuntu22
  runtime_version: 17
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: this field is required, but ignored

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
```

I proceeded as shown in the google cloud document, but only an error response is coming out.